# Grails support for consuming web services

Tags: grails

Does Grails provide built-in or via a plugin support to consume (not to generate) XML based REST or SOAP web services ( esp. REST) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.grails.org/plugin/rest

Comment: See http://www.grails.org/plugin/pusher for an example of the REST plugin in use.

Answer (score 3):

For SOAP based webservices, use [WSClient](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ws-client). The plugin is a wrapper around [GroovyWS](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS). Under the hood, Apache CXF is working there.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I created a script (grails create-script) that used wsimport to create POJOs in the java src directory. Each time the script ran, it would delete the generated directory if it existed first, then generate new files.

I did this because the API that was being consumed was being developed and I wanted an easy way to consume the latest and greatest when new functionality was added.

Answer (score 0):

In grails 3.x you can use the plugin in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2'
```

Then add the import to your controller like in http://guides.grails.org/grails-soap/guide/index.html

```
import wslite.soap.*
import wslite.soap.SOAPClient
import wslite.soap.SOAPResponse
```

and use as the example available in https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

```
def client = new SOAPClient('http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx')
def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
body {
    GetMothersDay('xmlns':'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
        year(2011)
    }
}
}

assert "2011-05-08T00:00:00" == response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
assert 200 == response.httpResponse.statusCode
assert "ASP.NET" == response.httpResponse.headers['X-Powered-By']

render (response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text())
```